# Relations between UserControl and MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

How could I make possible to access data/properties from a `UserControl` and the parent, `MainWindow` (and viceversa)? For example, say I have a `TextBox` in my `MainWindow` called `mainTextBox`. Then I create a `UserControl` with another `TextBox` called `ucTextBox`. I also have a button called `ucButton` in the `UserControl` that should popup a `MessageBox` with the product of the values `mainTextBox.Text * ucTextBox.Text` (converted to double, to make it work).

What I really want to know is how to achieve to do this dynamically, with a button that allows to create more `UserControls` that are capable to interact with the parent. In this case it makes no sense to name every `UserControl`.

I've tried several things, mainly with get,set properties but with no desired outcome.
I'm not sure if I need to use `UserControl`, but it seems to, I've read that `CustomControl` is for a deep customization but I don't need that.

Comment: Just use a model. Your main form will read/write to a (double) property in the model and each user control will access that property for reading. Take a look to [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28060/WPF-UserControl-DataTemplate) (well in your case you may not even need a data template).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is just a quick sample to get you started (and what probably was meant by mr. @Adriano):

**RootViewModel.cs**:

```
public class RootViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    private double _x;
    private double _y;

    public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }

    public double XY
    {
        get { return _x * _y; }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="200">
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="User Control">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Y:" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=1}" Margin="5" />
            <Button Content="Press me" Click="OnButtonClick" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = (RootViewModel)DataContext;
        var resultMessage = string.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}", viewModel.X, viewModel.Y, viewModel.XY);

        MessageBox.Show(resultMessage, "X * Y");
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfApplication21="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="Main Window" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="X:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=1}" Margin="5" Height="24" />
    </StackPanel>
    <WpfApplication21:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new RootViewModel
        {
            X = 5,
            Y = 7
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful! But as I'm very new in this world of ViewModels, what does DataContext = new RootViewModel really does? BTW, is this example adaptable to insert more UserControls and work independently? If I insert another, as it's binded to Y, all UserControls show the same value. Thank you.

Comment: In short - all of the visible elements in WPF have special property - **DataContext** which could contain any object and from which you could get (or set!) data for/from your this or other UI elements with special syntax in xaml called **Data Binding**. For long (but *extremely* important!) answer you should read more about data binding concept in WPF. Good place to start could be here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: As for adaptability for more UserControls - surely yes, but how to do this depends on what exactly you try to achieve.