# How can I get data from user Control in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have user control which has two controls
**Label** and **TextBlock**

```
   <UserControl x:Class=MyClass....
                 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="MyUsrCtrl">
      <StackPanel>
           <Label Content={Binding MyLabelContent} x:Name="MyLabel"...../>
           <TextBlock Content={Binding MyTextBlockContent} x:Name="MyTextBlock"...../>
     </StackPanel>

  </UserControl>
```

and In my MainWindow I have a ListBox whose ItemSource is binded to collection of this usercontrol

```
 <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_myControl}"> // collection of user controls
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

How can I get the value of the `Textblock` and `Label` when any item is selected in Listbox?

Comment: Use the SelectedItem Property of the ListBox.

Comment: It does not work when i click somewhere on textblock

Comment: try to look at this post: [Relations between usercontrol and main window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897188/relations-between-usercontrol-and-mainwindow

Comment: Just to verify: you are binding to a collection of user controls and then you're specifying a data template that displays these user controls as themselves?

Comment: The ItemsSource should not be bound to a collection of controls. Instead there should be a collection of data items (i.e. a class in your view model).

Comment: @Clemens can you post an example or point me to any link

Comment: The [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN is a good starting point. Instead of a UserControl you would simply create a DataTemplate with the Label and TextBlock. The DataTemplate may of course also contain your UserControl, but that is not strictly necessary.

Comment: "Collection of controls?"  Nope.  NOOOPE.  That isn't mvvm.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

- Created a model called MyControl that "represents" the data in MyUserControl
- Created an ObservableCollection That "represents" the data in the Listbox
- This way you can also the delete all the x:Name
- Seperates Data from UI

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}"
             SelectionChanged="MyListBox_OnSelectionChanged"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <local:MyUserControl></local:MyUserControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        MyControls = new ObservableCollection<MyControl>();
        var a = new MyControl { MyLabelContent = "label content 1", MyTextBlockContent = "Text content 1" };
        var b = new MyControl { MyLabelContent = "label content 2", MyTextBlockContent = "Text content 2" };

        MyControls.Add(a);
        MyControls.Add(b);

    }


    private void MyListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            var selectedItem = listBox.SelectedItems[0] as MyControl;

            var textBlockContent = selectedItem.MyTextBlockContent; //text in textblock
            var labelContent = selectedItem.MyLabelContent; //text in label

        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<MyControl> _myControls;


    public ObservableCollection<MyControl> MyControls
    {
        get { return _myControls; }
        set
        {
            _myControls = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyControls");
        }
    }


    #region PropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }


    #endregion


}
```

MyUserControl.XAML

```
   <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding MyLabelContent}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextBlockContent}" />
 </StackPanel>
```

MyControl.cs

```
 public class MyControl
{
    public string MyLabelContent { get; set; }
    public string MyTextBlockContent { get; set; }

}
```

Hopes this works for you :)

Here is a link to a working sample:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8O-XH0V_o1hNXprX2c0S0xJUFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Minor point but a common convention is to add the "ViewModel" suffix to VM class names. ie `MyControlViewModel`

Comment: Good point, Kinda just threw this up. You are welcome to edit :) @GazTheDestroyer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get TextBlock from selected item, you can do like this:

```
 var selectedUserControl = myListBox.SelectedItem as MyUserControl;
 TextBlock textBlock = selectedUserControl.MyTextBlock;
```

Hope helps!

Comment: This would require to make the MyTextBlock field (which is generated from the `x:Name` declaration) public. By default it is private.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, you are right by default elements accessibility is private, but I test this and I can get access to this element